# In what exact cases should staging / beta and production / stable environments share a database?

Tags: deployment, production-environment, staging

In my past and current web development positions, Staging / Beta and Production / Stable environments have shared a database.

Here's my understanding of what is going on:

- Staging / Beta is basically identical to Production / Stable's server(s), except the public at large cannot access Staging / Beta
- Once QA's tests pass the upcoming iteration of code on its own sanitized subset copy of Production / Stable data, the next step in the development is to make sure that the upcoming iteration of code will work with the full set of Production / Stable data while not breaking the existing Production / Stable website - that's the purpose of Staging / Beta.  Also, a company can let beta-testers test out the code using the same data which the world at large can see.  Then, when the beta-testers give the thumbs up, it should be a simple switch from the older iteration to the newer iteration of code.

One of my direct reports called this a "smell".  He suggests that Staging / Beta should have a full and complete copy of Production / Stable's database -- thus if there truly is a problem with Staging / Beta code which was not caught during QA, it won't affect the Production / Stable experience.  That was the answer with these two links:

- [Staging enviornment setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572709/1276572)
- [Staging database predicament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451519/staging-database-predicament)

So here's my question: in what exact cases SHOULD Staging / Beta and Production / Stable share a database server?  Or are my current and previous companies doing things wrong / being cheap / etc.?

Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing resources should only be done if you don't have enough resources :)

I have to agree with your direct report.  A couple of issues you can run into, and they aren't too uncommon:

1. The process of testing steals resources from production.
2. New code is broken an consumes way too many resources (variation on #1)
3. New code requires a new schema that can't live easily side-by-side with the production schema.
4. In the process of installing changes for beta, you break production.

I really don't see how you can excuse not hosting staging/beta separately.

Comment: What if we are building an app like WhatsApp? In WhatsApp, it is possible for a beta user and production user can be in a same group. Do they share one single database for production and beta versions of the app? I am aking this because we are building a similar kind of android app that having "User Groups".

Comment: @MathewJohn Your confusion here regards the difference of clients and servers.  A Beta WhatsApp user is using a Beta Client that connects to same production WhatsApp service as a production WhatsApp user.

Answer (score 4):

The goal seems to be:

1. Allow for the new version for a subset of users (great for agile work flow)
2. avoid data loss or unique key loss/duplication since both versions run concurrently

I am in a similar environment, and I can't seem to find a documented development life cycle that allows for the above. I would say it is a cross between **A/B Testing** and "[**Canary Release Strategy**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html)".

We solved this with a fourth environment, between testing and production (we call it beta even though it is actually production):

1. **alpha** developer testing.  This is where developers push branches and merge code.
2. **QA/staging** user testing.  This will be identical to production once new version is released.)
3. **beta** production for a subset of users. (we are trying to come up with a better name since having production data on "beta" makes auditors nervous.. I'm not sure if "canary" will fly... no pun intended.
4. **www** (Generally Available production)

Show stoppers should never make it to beta (in this context) since it *is* production, which is separate from staging/QA.

If you like this answer, maybe you can name the release cycle or deployment strategy after me :)